# Making HTTPS requests using a provided x509 certificate on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm interested if Google App Engine provides a way to use a X.509 Certificate to create a HTTPS connection (the server where I have to connect provides the public certificate - to encrypt data that I send and the private key to decrypt the data received from that server).

According to this post https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-python/C9RSDGeIraE it's not possible but 3 years passed since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL client certificates are not currently supported. The feature request is [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3719).

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine has the ability to work with SSL certificate on your custom domain, that means the you can assign a certificate to a domain that is running on the AppEngine.
You cannot AFAIK make a request and provide a custom certificate per request.

[Documentation on AppEngine SSL.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl)