# Can I start and shutdown an Azure VM via web requests?

Tags: web-services, azure

I have a usage case where I need to send the `azure vm start myvmname` and `azure vm shutdown myvmname` commands via a web request.

The intention is to use only on demand instances in the workflow.

So far, I have a static front end on CloudFront, which sends an http request to an intermediary cloud web service, with the intention that this can start and stop my Azure VMs similar to using the NodeJS command line tools.

Preferences for the intermediary service are GAE, Azure or if there is a pay as you go option within AWS that would suit (constantly running an EC2 or Azure VM instance just for this purpose would be overkill).

The CloudFront static front end and Azure VMs for processing are not replaceable in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Node.js cross-platform CLI uses the [Windows Azure Service Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) to perform all its actions. This is a public API which uses an X.509 certificate for authentication. The REST API exposes operations to manage Virtual Machines including a [Start Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157189.aspx) and [Shutdown Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157195.aspx) (with the word Role being a synonym for VM).

Note that Shutdown Role deallocates the VM completely, causing it to lose its internal IP address. Performing Shutdown Role on the only VM in the Virtual Machine cloud service causes it to lose its public VIP as well.

Comment: Thanks Neil, that sounds promising. If I'm assuming correctly, to fulfil my requirements, I would need to be able to send my REST API commands from an on demand web service that allows uploading the X.509 certificate? It seems from this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360099/making-https-requests-using-a-provided-x509-certificate-on-google-app-engine) that it may not be possible on GAE, but do you know of an alternative way with GAE or an Azure cloud instance that would support this?

Awarding answer as it does answer the base question.

Comment: I don't know anything about GAE, but a quick search turned up a post on the Cloud Security API and specifically a getPublicCertificatesForApp() method that might be a starting point.  
The trick to getting an X.509 certificate onto a Windows Azure PaaS cloud role instance is to upload it both as a management certificate and as a service certificate. The latter allows the Fabric Controller to deploy the X.509 certificate to each instance in the role.  
With regard to Windows Azure Web Sites, you could upload the certificate to Windows Azure Blob Storage and retrieve it from there.